# ¿Cómo cambiar el texto de un botón dentro de un datagridview?

Tags: c#

Tengo estas columnas:

```
Fecha        Hora       Envio       Estado fruta   (Columna del boton)

                         4             Limpio                Cortado

                         5             Sucio                  Lavado
```

Quiero el boton dentro de un datagrid se cambie de texto segun el estado del cultivo, si el estado es limpio el texto del boton sea cortado, si el estado del cultivo es sucio el texto del boton sea Lavado

El código es que tengo al momento es este:

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn btn_clean_chopped = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

            btn_clean_chopped.Name = "btn_clean_chopped";
            btn_clean_chopped.HeaderText = "";
            //btn_clean_chopped.Text = "Lavado";
            btn_clean_chopped.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

            table.Columns.Add(btn_clean_chopped);

            for (int fila = 0; fila < table.Rows.Count; fila++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < table.Rows[fila].Cells.Count; col++)
                {
                    string valor = table.Rows[fila].Cells["clean"].Value.ToString();
                    //string valor = table.CurrentRow.Cells["clean"].Value.ToString();
                    //MessageBox.Show(valor.ToString());
                    if (valor == "Sucio")
                    {
                        btn_clean_chopped.Text = "Lavado";
                        break;
                    }

                    if (valor == "Limpio")
                    {
                        btn_clean_chopped.Text = "Cortado";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Para agregar una columna de tipo botón puede hacerlo así:**

```
var button=new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
button.Name="NombreBoton";
button.HeaderText="Encabezado";
button.Text = "Texto";
button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
```

**Para establecer el texto de la columna del botón dinámicamente**

Para mostrar el texto de "Lavado" en cada botón, es suficiente para establecer:

```
button.Text = "Lavado";
button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Además, si necesita establecer texto diferente para los botones, puede usar el evento `CellFormatting` del `DataGridView` y Establecer el valor de esas celdas:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //// Si esta es una fila de encabezado o una fila nueva, no haga nada
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    // Si formatea su columna deseada, establezca el valor
    if (e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["clean"].Index)
    {
          //Puedes poner tu lógica dinámica aquí
          //y usa diferentes valores basados en otros valores de celda,
          //por ejemplo celda "clean"
          string valor = datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["clean"].Value.ToString();

          if (valor.Equals("Sucio"))
              button.Text = "Lavado";
          else
          if (valor.Equals("Limpio"))
              button.Text = "Cortado";


       //this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["clean"].Value
       //e.Value = "Lavado";
    }
}
```

Debe asignar este controlador al evento `CellFormating`:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;
```

¿Desea vincular el texto de DataGridViewButtonColumn al DataSource de DataGridView? De ser así, establezca DataPropertyName para la columna a través de las opciones Editar columna.

De lo contrario, puede intentar usar el evento CellFormatting de DataGridView:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
     {
        e.Value = "Algun Valor";
     }
 }
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda, Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < table.Rows.Count; fila++)
{                
    string valor = table.Rows[fila].Cells["clean"].Value.ToString();                   
    if (valor == "Sucio")
    {
        table.Rows[fila].Cells["btn_clean_chopped"].Value = "Lavado";            
    }
    if (valor == "Limpio")
    {
        table.Rows[fila].Cells["btn_clean_chopped"].Value = "Cortado";
    }                
}
```

Comment: Hola Fernando. Ya te puse un comentario en otra publicacion. Las respuestas tienen una calidad minima. No es de calidad el publicar solo el codigo y ya. Has de explicar donde estaba su error y como funciona y como tu respuesta soluciona su problema. Mira [answer] para mas info. Un saludo